# Logic Needed for after Parsing Json

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @userid int
SET @userid=3
SET @json =  
N'[{"ID":1,"Roles":[1,2]},{"ID":2, "Roles":[1,2,3]},{"ID":3,"Roles":[1,2,3,4]}]'

BEGIN
 SELECT ID, R.[Value] AS [Role]
FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH (
    ID INT, 
    [Roles] NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON
)
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([Roles]) R
end
```

Above query giving below result.

```
ID ROLE
1   1
1   2
2   1
2   2
2   3
3   1
3   2
3   3
3   4

CREATE TABLE A(ID INT,ROLE INT)
```

i want logic to compare above QUERY output with another table(table A) whether above ID is present or not if ID Is present in that table then Role is present or not for corresponding ID,if Role is not present i want to insert Role for the ID.

Comment: Seems like a LEFT JOIN would solve this.

Comment: `EXCEPT` is probably your friend. `MERGE` is usable as well, but has a substantial learning curve. From the way you've formulated the question it's unclear if one query is sufficient, or you need two.

Comment: @ram You want to fill table `a`?

Comment: Yes i used except in my query.it is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use `EXCEPT` to filter rows that are not already present in the table:

```
DECLARE @a TABLE (ID INT, ROLE INT);
INSERT INTO @a VALUES
(1, 2),
(2, 2),
(3, 3);

INSERT INTO @a
SELECT ID, R.[Value] AS [Role]
FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH (
    ID INT, 
    [Roles] NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON
)
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([Roles]) R
EXCEPT
SELECT ID, ROLE
FROM @a;
```

[Test](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=02f3c3e1f36c530d0d7820635ec00f63)